# Accounting for Team Size on Clique Cohesion?

Tags: social-network, social-science

So, right now, I'm trying to model cohesion for different size team. Imagine, we're talking about in-person social interactions. Every person is divided into different teams.

I'm interested in how human's cohesion levels will decrease as team size increases (presumably it gets harder for each person to interact with each other person as the team increases. Right now, I'm measuring cohesion as the completed triangles over all total triangles (or triads.).

Does anyone know of previous research around this area? I'm interested to find out what's already been asked about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

@Stephen, what is your original task? Could you please give a some details?

in the paper (Pijl et al., 2011) compared two methods for the assessment of students’ friendship networks: the reciprocal nomination method and social cognitive mapping. In total, 190 participants took part in the experiment. The authors introduced types of isolated students in their study: a) a student with no reciprocated links at all (type 1), and b) a student with one reciprocated link (type 2). A cohesive subgroup defined as a group of at least three students a) who have more internal links than external links, b) are connected by some path to each of the group members and remain connected when up to 10% of the group is removed.

Pijl, S.J., Koster, M., Hannink, A., Stratingh, A.: Friends in the classroom: a comparison between two methods for the assessment of students’ friendship networks. Soc Psychol Educ (14), 475–488 (2011)